# Responsive content slider

Tags: responsive-slides, circular-content-carousel

I am currently using and excellent content slider for team profiles based on:

http://tympanus.net/Development/CircularContentCarousel/

I am showing images of team members and when you click the more link, it show more information about that person.

Unfortunately, there is not a responsive version of this and I would love to find a similar slider that would work responsive.

Could anybody help?